# Can't understand what saveLayer() do in canvas android

Tags: java, android, canvas, view, drawing

can any one explains to me in simple way what does `canvas.saveLayer()` exactly mean ? , I'm beginner in android canvas.

I tried the method in this code :

```
canvas.drawRect(50,50,300,300,paint);
canvas.saveLayer(0,0,0,0,paint);
canvas.drawRect(250,250,400,400,paint);
```

The second rectangle disappears and I don't know why

Comment: The 2nd rectangle disappears because the 0, 0, 0, 0 in saveLayer parameters means your layer has no dimensions.